# How to create a Tinder type UINavigationController?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uinavigationcontroller

I have went through some tutorials and example projects to find out a way to create a UINavigationController like in the Tinder app. This is the best example that I've got so far : https://github.com/Tgy31/THTinderNavigationController

But the problem I'm facing is, I have no idea to animate the buttons like in the Tinder app. Please check this image:

[image: Please check this image:]

Does anyone know how to achieve this?